# I am trying to filter array of objects (courses) with array of unique data (tag) using checkbox button using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

I am trying to filter array of objects (courses) with array of unique data (tag) using
checkbox button using react hooks. Its not working. please help me to add checked inside
<input type="checkbox" checked={ } />

Its working fine if input type="radio" but not working for type="checkbox"

```
import { useState } from "react";

const courses = [
{ id: "1", course: "React Tutorial", tag: "react" },
{ id: "2", course: "Object-oriented programming (OOP)", tag: "oop" },
{ id: "3", course: "Java Programming", tag: "java" },
{ id: "4", course: "JavaScript Course", tag: "javascript" },
{ id: "5", course: "Spring Boot Tutorial", tag: "spring" },
{ id: "6", course: "Python Bootcamp", tag: "python" },
{ id: "7", course: "Spring Framework Course", tag: "spring" },
{ id: "8", course: "React with Redux", tag: "react" },
{ id: "9", course: "C#: Classes and OOP", tag: "oop" },
{ id: "10", course: "Java Masterclass", tag: "java" },
{ id: "11", course: "ES6 JavaScript Training", tag: "javascript" },
{ id: "12", course: "Learn Python Programming", tag: "python" },
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map((item) => item.tag))];

const App = () => {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState("all");
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState(courses);

const handleFilterItems = (tag: any) => {
setChecked(tag);
if (tag !== "all") {
  const filteredItems = courses.filter((item) => item.tag === tag);
  setFilterData(filteredItems);
} else {
  setFilterData(courses);
}
};

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={checked === "all"}
    onChange={() => handleFilterItems("all")}
  />{" "}
  All
  {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked === tag}
        onChange={() => handleFilterItems(tag)}
      />
      {tag}
    </div>
  ))}
  {filterData.map((course) => (
    <li key={course.id}>
      {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
    </li>
  ))}
</div>
);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

the checkbox filtering logic needs some fix. Please find my solution - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chaplygin-0ot56e?file=/src/App.js

```
    const courses = [
  { id: "1", course: "React Tutorial", tag: "react" },
  { id: "2", course: "Object-oriented programming (OOP)", tag: "oop" },
  { id: "3", course: "Java Programming", tag: "java" },
  { id: "4", course: "JavaScript Course", tag: "javascript" },
  { id: "5", course: "Spring Boot Tutorial", tag: "spring" },
  { id: "6", course: "Python Bootcamp", tag: "python" },
  { id: "7", course: "Spring Framework Course", tag: "spring" },
  { id: "8", course: "React with Redux", tag: "react" },
  { id: "9", course: "C#: Classes and OOP", tag: "oop" },
  { id: "10", course: "Java Masterclass", tag: "java" },
  { id: "11", course: "ES6 JavaScript Training", tag: "javascript" },
  { id: "12", course: "Learn Python Programming", tag: "python" }
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map((item) => item.tag))];
const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(uniqueTags);
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState(courses);

  const handleFilterItems = (event, tag) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      if (tag === "all") {
        setFilterData(courses);
        setChecked(uniqueTags);
      } else {
        setChecked([...checked, tag]);
        const addedData = courses.filter((item) => item.tag === tag);
        setFilterData([...filterData, ...addedData]);
      }
    } else {
  if (tag === "all") {
    setFilterData([]);
    setChecked([]);
  } else {
    const removedData = filterData.filter((item) => item.tag !== tag);
    setFilterData(removedData);
    setChecked(checked.filter((item) => item !== tag));
  }
}
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked.length === uniqueTags.length}
        onChange={(event) => handleFilterItems(event, "all")}
      />{" "}
      All
      {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked.includes(tag)}
            onChange={(event) => handleFilterItems(event, tag)}
          />
          {tag}
        </div>
      ))}
      {filterData.map((course) => (
        <li key={course.id}>
          {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  ); 
};
```